# WordPress: widget is always there even if I de-active its plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a developer who is new to WordPress, I made my first plugin with simple widget.

I'm using genesis with simple sidebar plugin. my problem is the widget I made appears in all my WordPress pages. even if the page's sidebar doesn't have that widget. I checked all sidebars and the widget is not there. I de-active the plugin and the widget is still appears in all WordPress pages. that drives me crazy. please any solution ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please paste the code you used to make the widget?

Comment: Are you using a cache, like WP super cache? If so, for testing, set the option where logged in users don't get the pages cached, and test while you're logged in. Or test on a local version without the cache enabled.

Comment: @Matt, wow that was fast, 100% true. my fault, may you please post as an answer to accept it !

Comment: ME Well, it was kind of halfway between an answer and a complete guess, so I figured a comment would be a better way to start! Posted as answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your widget is still appearing on your pages when the plugin is turned off, that's a good sign that you're looking at a cached page, as served by WP Super Cache, for example.

Double-check by looking at the page source. Most caches will include information in comments at the top or bottom of the page to show that the page has been served from a cache. In WP Super Cache's case, for example, you might see lines at the bottom of the page like this:

```
<!-- Dynamic page generated in 0.293 seconds. -->
<!-- Cached page generated by WP-Super-Cache on 2011-01-20 13:48:56 -->
<!-- super cache -->
```

If that is the case, the options are:

- Test your plugin locally, on a test server with caching disabled
- Turn off your cache
- Turn on the cache option that disables caching for logged-in users, and test while logged in.

Either way, if you're using a cache, it's best to test a plugin both with and without the cache, as caching might have adverse effect.